# How to execute the scripts in procedure in parallel

Tags: stored-procedures

I have to execute the scripts in procedure parallely so that it will decrease the execute time of procedure. Can anyone please help here.
   My procedure is as below.I just want all the select statement in my procedure should start executing at exact time.Please help me , I want this in my project.Pleae let me know if futhure details are required.
   The insert statement must not start at the same time. It will be okay if it executed sequenntially;
Plea

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
        PROCEDURE "test_proc"(
            p_fromdate DATE)
        AS
          fromdate DATE;
          todate DATE;
          emp_id            NUMBER := 0;
          emp_address       NUMBER := 0;
          emp_dob           NUMBER := 0;
          emp_doj           NUMBER := 0;
          emp_msisdn        NUMBER := 0;
          emp_name          NUMBER := 0;
          emp_vehicl_number NUMBER := 0;
          emp_vehicl_type   NUMBER := 0;
          emp_middle_name   NUMBER := 0;
          emp_last_name     NUMBER := 0;
        BEGIN
          SELECT id INTO emp_id FROM employee ;
          SELECT address INTO emp_address FROM employee ;
          SELECT dob INTO emp_dob FROM employee ;
          SELECT doj INTO emp_doj FROM employee ;
          SELECT msisdn INTO emp_msisdn FROM employee ;
          SELECT name INTO emp_name FROM employee ;
          SELECT vehicle_number INTO emp_vehicl_number FROM employee ;
          SELECT vehicle_type INTO emp_vehicl_type FROM employee ;
          SELECT middlename INTO emp_middle_name FROM employee ;
          SELECT lastNAme INTO emp_last_name FROM employee ;
          INSERT
          INTO test
            (
              idofEmp,
              Empaddress,
              Empdob,
              Empdoj,
              Empmsisdn,
              Empname,
              Empvehicle_number,
              Empvehicle_type,
              Empmiddlename,
              EmplastNAme
            )
            VALUES
            (
              emp_id,
              emp_address,
              emp_dob,
              emp_doj,
              emp_msisdn,
              emp_name,
              emp_vehicl_number,
              emp_vehicl_type,
              emp_middle_name,
              emp_last_name
            );
        END;
```

Comment: Please take a moment to study the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); then please edit your question and fix the formatting. Thank you!

Comment: Done .Please help me now

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? (Please add the corresponding tag to your question... Thanks.)

Comment: That all being said, I don't think that standard SQL generally gives you the option to specify what should be executed in parallel. Your RDBMS might however be smart enough to parallelize query execution automatically without you ever knowing. Another option might be to take these queries out of the SP and have your application code send these queries to the DB server in parallel.